# ImageJ plugin that draws a white frame inside of a ROI

Tags: java, border, frame, imagej

I am trying to create a plugin on ImageJ that creates a 10 pixels wide frame inside of the ROI. I am having trouble doing this, the code I have so far simply fills in the the entire space start 10 pixels in the ROI. The code I have is below.

```
import ij.*;
import ij.plugin.filter.PlugInFilter;
import ij.process.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Frame implements PlugInFilter {

    public int setup(String arg, ImagePlus imp) {
        if (arg.equals("about"))
            {showAbout(); return DONE;}
        return DOES_8G+DOES_STACKS+SUPPORTS_MASKING;
    }

    public void run(ImageProcessor ip) {
        byte[] pixels = (byte[])ip.getPixels();
        int width = ip.getWidth();
        Rectangle r = ip.getRoi();
        int offset, i;
        for (int y=r.y+10; y<(r.y+r.height)-10; y++) {
            offset = y*width;
            for (int x=r.x+10; x<(r.x+r.width)-10; x++) {
                i = offset + x ;
                pixels[i] = (byte)(255);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try it the hard (i.e. low level API) way?

Using ImageJ's [command recorder](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-31.html#sub%3aRecord...) (*Plugins > Macros > Record...* and setting "Record:" to *Java*), you can quickly get the required Java code after

- creating a selection,
- adding it to the [ROI manager](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-30.html#sub%3aROI-Manager...),
- running *Edit > Selection > [Enlarge...](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-27.html#sub%3aEnlarge...)*,
- adding the new ROI to the manager,
- combining the two ROIs using *XOR*, and
- filling the resulting selection with the foreground color.

The code would look like this:

```
import ij.IJ;
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.plugin.frame.RoiManager;

// [...]

RoiManager rm = RoiManager.getInstance();
if (rm==null) rm = new RoiManager();
rm.runCommand("Deselect");
if (rm.getCount() > 0) rm.runCommand("Delete");
ImagePlus imp = IJ.getImage();
// imp.setRoi(30, 50, 150, 100);
rm.addRoi(imp.getRoi());
IJ.run(imp, "Enlarge...", "enlarge=-10");
rm.addRoi(imp.getRoi());
rm.setSelectedIndexes(new int[]{0,1});
rm.runCommand("XOR");
IJ.run(imp, "Fill", "slice");
imp.show();
```

Comment: @eglinger I have to do it the hard way for my assignment